# 'Ignoring' an object without completely deleting it

Tags: java, bluej

I'm making a basic Space Invaders style game where the player can move the ship and shoot enemies. The enemies have no guns but the player has one gun on either side of the ship. If the ship is destroyed, the gun that destroyed it gets       (1 + (7-N)) points if the previous ship was destroyed N moves ago by the same gun. For reference, this is the code that I used to implement this points system:

```
public void destroy()
   {
       if (moveNum != 0)
       {
           if (moveNum <= 8)
           {
               points += 1 + (8 - moveNum);
               moveNum = 0;
           }
           else
           {
               ++points;
               moveNum = 0;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           ++points;
       }
       moveNum++;
   }
```

When the player fires, I have if-statements that check to see whether any enemies were hit and whether or not they were destroyed. The if-statements are nested so that the program checks whether either gun 1 or 2 hits any of the three enemies. Again, for reference, this is the basic format of the if-statement:

```
if (playerPos + 1 == enemy2.position())
    {
        power = player.power(2);
        enemy2.gotHit(power);

        if (enemy2.health() <= 0)
        {
            player.destroy(2);
        }
    }
```

In this instance, the program checks to see if gun2 has the same position as enemy2, in which case the enemy is hit and damage is taken equal to the gun's power. If the enemy is destroyed (life == 0), points are awarded to that gun as described above.

Now the if-statements are nested so that (for example) it checks if gun 1 hit enemy 1, then inside that if-statement, it checks to see whether gun 2 hit enemy 2 or enemy 3.

The checks are repeated in different series: (gun1-enemy1, gun2-enemy2/3), (gun2-enemy1, gun1-enemy2/3), etc.

The problem is, even if an enemy was destroyed, the next if-statement checks it again and because the life is still zero, it add more points.

So my question is, if an enemy is destroyed, how do I ignore the enemy for the next set of if-statements? I read that I can assign a `null` value but I can't do this without knowing which enemy will be destroyed (which of course I won't know).

PS Sorry if this is too long, I've tried making it as short as I can :P

Comment: Can't you just check the health again during the second check?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I do check the health but that is the problem, the ship was already destroyed but because the health is still zero or less, it adds points every time the it runs the check

Comment: Then you could create a `destroyed` bool variable, set it to `true` when the ship is destroyed, then check that. If the ship was `destroyed` on the first shot, don't apply the score bonus on the second check. Where you'd declare the `destroyed` variable though would depend on the greater context.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This is for an assignment and I'm afraid I can't add any extra fields

Comment: I don't think I could write an answer for this without more context. It would be more of a shot in the dark than anything, and I try not to half-ass answers.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh ok, well thanks anyway :)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be added as a field. Do both shot checks in a single function, and declare the bool flag at the top of the function. You just need to do some rearranging.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ah that may work. Thank you again lol

Comment: I will note though that I'm not suggesting copying a ton of code into a single function. Ideally, you should have a `checkShot` function that you use to check each individual shot. Think what if you want to add a third cannon? That would just result in a third call to `checkShot`. Then, you don't even need to call `checkShot` a second (or third) time if the first one destroys the ship. Don't run code if you don't want its effects in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you had in mind but I basically have a `destroyed` boolean for each enemy and I have an if-statement that checks to see if this is false before continuing to do the `life == 0` check. I don't think I can add a separate function for this with the way I have described. If you are thinking about another way that could use a `checkShot` function, I'd love to hear it

Comment: Again, I'd need more context. Generalizing is always difficult, but it can be accomplished usually just by comparing code. Write out the full code for checking each shot, then compare them and see what differs. Make the differing parts parameters of the function, then pass that information in. Sorry, I'm heading to bed, so I can't help more. Generalizing code is though, at worst, good practice, so I'd try and see what you can come up with. It will always simplify things later if you've set things up right.

Comment: @Carcigenicate No worries and thanks for everything